# javascript accessing the name of the parameters for debugging purposes

Tags: javascript, web

is there anyway to access the "name" of the parameter as such:

```
function(arg1, arg2) {
    debug("arg1 is rotten!");
}
```

Right now if i change the parameter name I'd have to change the name within the string as well, so I was looking if javascript had a solution like [How do i bind function arguments to the parameters i supply in creating an ArgumentException object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042374/how-do-i-bind-function-arguments-to-the-parameters-i-supply-in-creating-an-argume)

I want a way to be able to do something like:

```
function(arg1, arg2) {
        debug(arguments[0].name+" is rotten!");
    }
```

so that I would not have to search for the changes and change accordingly whenever i change the name of the parameter (sometimes its used more than once!)

Comment: To get the first arguments, you can use `arguments[0]` etc. The name then doesn't matter. (But then again the order is important, of course)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your problem.. but that's completely normal that you have to change code if you change a parameter name unless that parameter is not used answhere..

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's not normal at all.

Comment: @pimvdb i mean i need the name of the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access variable names, only their values.  The closest you can get is if your argument to your method is an 'options' style object (which is just a regular JavaScript object, but calling it 'options' or 'opts' and having that contain all your arguments is a very common practice):

```
function test(opts){
    for(var name in opts){
        console.log(name + ' with value ' + opts[name] + ' is rotten!')
    }
}

test({arg1: 'argument 1', arg2: 'argument 2'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a function, there is an array in the function called `arguments` that holds all the arguments in it

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/P5FvN/

Comment: I think he actually wants the name of the variable, not just access to it's value in arguments

Comment: @Matt +10 for understanding the question

Comment: wasn't me, but I'm guessing it's because you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @user90070, well there is no way to actually get the arguments names unless u did a hack like @Matt has done in his answer

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function show_me() {
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
    }
}

show_me('a', 'b');
```

Comment: you may want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009911/javascript-get-argument-value-and-name-of-passed-variable